# How to map buttons on my mouse with AppleScript?

Tags: applescript, mouse, gesture

Since BetterTouchTool is becoming paid, I was looking for an alternative solutions to map my navigation buttons (prev. page, next page) on my mouse (Logitech MX518) that I enjoy using for browsing websites. Right now these two button perform the same action like pressing the scroll wheel.

I already tried Logitech's own software but that seems to be a rather overkill solution and apart from using too much resources, it is also too obtrusive while booting up.

So I was wondering if there is an easy solution with AppleScript that I could write to just do this trick of mapping a button on my mouse to possibly a swipe gesture (like on trackpads)?

Comment: You're not willing to pay $3 for it?

Comment: @user3439894 not just for the simple mapping of my mouse's buttons. If I would use more of the other features it offers, maybe. If Logitech's "Gaming" Software wouldn't suck (the normal HID software is much better), I would use that. But this way I can invest those $3 for a new mouse instead ;-)

Comment: You could perhaps use [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) and [use this as a guide](https://github.com/tekezo/Karabiner/blob/master/src/core/server/Resources/include/checkbox/devices/logitech_m560.xml) to create your own [private.xml file](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en#privatexml) with the help of [Event viewer](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/document.html.en#eventviewer)

Comment: @Joonas that sounds like a possible way to do it but I was hoping that I could do this rather simple task with OS X's own tools.

Comment: Some mice let you save profiles in the on-board memory. I personally use Logitech mmo mouse with my mac and since I can save the button mapping to the mouse itself, I only have to open logitech gaming software whenever I need to change things. So it doesn't have to stay open in the background. Obviously this isn't the cheapest mouse...

Comment: @Joonas  That would be great but unfortunately my mouse is probably too old for that.. But I was looking forward to upgrade at one point to the MX Master maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Karabiner, which Joonas suggested, natively has back/forward options for buttons 4 and 5. You do not have to create a xtml file.
The option is under 'pointing device' > 'button to key' > 'use button 4 and 5 as back/forward'.
I have only used it for 30 minutes so far, but it worked straight away by just activating those checkmarks (mouse: ttesports black v2)

Comment: I tried it but unfortunately with my mouse (or maybe localization?) this doesn't work. In Firefox one button zooms in, the other one doesn't do anything, in Finder both buttons don't have any effect. :-/